# Light description language of restful web services

Tags: xml, json, web-services, rest, wsdl

i need to describe my restful web services, so i can process it easily. I tried with wsdl 2.0 and now trying with wadl, but i am curious if there is a language that use JSON instead of XML?

thx for help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a WSDL-like mechanism for JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538131/is-there-a-wsdl-like-mechanism-for-json)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool to generate a JSON schema from an XML schema through Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754240/is-there-a-tool-to-generate-a-json-schema-from-an-xml-schema-through-java)